# Rails: onchange posting not sending param

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I may have misdiagnosed in the title, but here is the problem:

I have a form_for which grabs a users search selection. I wanted it to post onchange, so I added the appropiate html attibute:

```
<%=form_for @search_select, :url=> {:action=>"search"} do |g|%>
<select name="search_select[selection]" id="selection" onchange="this.form.submit()">
 <option value"">Search...</option>
 <%@searches.each do |s|%>
  <option value=<%=s%>><%=s.capitalize%></option>
 <%end%>
<%end%>
```

But when I try to get the param in the controller, I get a "no method" error:

```
if @search_select.selection=="stores"
```

And this is my route:

```
post 'search'  => 'home#search_post'
```

Am a labeling something wrong? Is this a bad implementation of onchange? What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all GET/POST params are in the variable named `params`

try params[:search_select]